# How get only number data type as parameter in function Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, function, numbers

oddeven("asd") output keep showing asd is odd. How to make it show asd is not a number?

```
   let num;

    function oddeven(num){
        num = parseInt(num);

        if(num%2 == 0){
            document.write(num + " is even" + "<br>");
        }else if(num%2 != 0){
            document.write(num + " is odd" + "<br>")
        }else
            document.write(num + " is not a number" + "<br>");
    }
    oddeven(2);
    oddeven(1);
    oddeven(10);
    oddeven(7);
    oddeven("asd");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your function to check for non-numbers like this:

```
function oddeven(num) {
    if (isNaN(num)) {
        document.write(num + " is not a number" + "<br>");
    } else {
        num = parseInt(num);
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
        document.write(num + " is even" + "<br>");
        } else {
        document.write(num + " is odd" + "<br>")
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
problem in your code: in the case of `oddeven("asd")`, your variable `num` was being set as `NaN` so your second test was passing.

Comment: Tested and works. So the main thing here is to add isNaN() on the top of the function. Thank you.

Comment: yes, it is always a good idea to validate the data type before performing an operation on it; please mark as answer if it was helpfull :-)